# How do you integrate a javascript timer to countdown to count from a ruby variable?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timer

I am working on a really simple ruby on rails app. I am trying to build a workout timer.  There is a `Workout` resource with a `duration` attribute. The user can choose to set the workout to 15 or 30 minutes.

I have a Javascript code that counts down for the duration.  I can't figure out how to set the timer to countdown from the `workout.duration`.

This is the Ruby that will put out a duration in minutes.

```
    Total workout time: <%= @workout.duration %>
```

Where or how do I pass this variable in the Javascript code? This is the Javascript that counts down:

```
<script>
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}


var timeInSeconds = 30;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInSeconds*1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<h1>Timer</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to assume that this is called from the `WorkoutController`, and that this timer applies to the `show` view.

You can put the static Javascript functions in `app/assets/javascripts/workout.js`, and it will be included in your asset pipeline:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}
```

You can add the dynamic Javascript to the end of the HTML in `app/views/workouts/show.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Timer</h1>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var timeInSeconds = <%= @workout.duration * 60 %>;
var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInSeconds*1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

Technically, since only `timeInSeconds` is variable, you could convert the other lines into a static Javascript function and include it in `app/assets/javascripts/workout.js`, as well:

```
function deadlineFromMinutes(minutes) {
  var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
  return new Date(currentTime + timeInSeconds*1000);
}
```

and change the `<script></script>` snippet in `app/views/workouts/show.html.erb` to look like this:

```
<script>
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadlineFromMinutes(<%= @workout.duration %>)
</script>
```

This will keep the dynamic parts cleanly separated from the static parts, which will save a little page render time, and make more of the Javascript code reusable with other parts of the application.

And that's all there is to using a combination of static and dynamic Javascript from within your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the `.js` file to `.erb.js` to enable embedded ruby templating. Then you can use the `<%= %>` syntax like you would in an HTML template:

```
var timeInSeconds = parseInt(<%= 30 %>);
```